# vitalpoltava star rating - issue assigning rating-percent dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am using [this](https://github.com/vitalpoltava/Star-Rating) angular star rating pluging

Just wanted to know if anyone has used it and assigned `rating-percent` dynamically.

I am doing something like this -

```
<div star-rating stars="5" outer-star-selection="stars" outer-percent="rating" rating-define="percent" readonly="true" rating-percent="StarRatingPropertyFromScope" star-radius="20" sel-color="gold" back-color="white" style="width:70%;"></div>
```

The issue for me is when i am assigning value to `StarRatingPropertyFromScope` attribute on controller scope using some service call, the value is not getting assigned to the star rating pluging.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: really! no one has used this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

`rating-percent` is treated as an attribute and isn't being watched dynamically. So, in case you badly want it, you can modify the plugin and pass that variable using '=' in `scope` isolating part (and, probably, some other minor changes will be needed)...